# Error while executing "npm run build"

Tags: node.js, npm, deployment, build, polymer

I can't resolve this unexpected problem !

This problem appeared while executing `npm run build`:

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! *********@1.2.0 build: `gulp`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the *********@1.2.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\********\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-
24T13_43_52_760Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Consider adding the aforementioned log to your post.

Comment: What does the package.json look like?